# Error occured while installing the sharepoint hosted app for sharepoint onpremises 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have developed and deploying the sample sharepoint hosted app for sharepoint onpremises 2013.but i am unable to deploying the sharepoint hosted app.

I am getting the  message in Output window while deploying is:

> "Installation is in Progress"

for 30 Minutes and after that getting following error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': Failed
>   to install app for SharePoint.